# VSCode, how to exclude settings.json from editor.formatOnSave

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, settings, ignore

I set `editor.formatOnSave` to `true` in settings.json, so every files (e.g. python, json, jsonc, etc.) is formatted on save. But I don't want to format automatically only when I edit `settings.json`.

I tried to add `// fmt: off` and `// @ts-nocheck` on first line of settings.json, but strings in settings.json were formatted automatically on save.

Could you tell me solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps:

1. Open your user or workspace settings in VS Code. You can do this by pressing Ctrl + , or Cmd + , on your keyboard.
2. Click on the "Open Settings (JSON)" icon in the top-right corner of the Settings tab. This opens the settings.json file.
3. Add or modify the "editor.formatOnSave" setting in your settings.json file to include an exception for the settings.json file. Also, include the "files.exclude" setting.
4. The "files.exclude" setting uses glob patterns to match files and directories to be excluded from certain operations. In this case, it's set to exclude any file named settings.json in any directory.
5. Save the settings.json file.

Comment: give an example for `3.`. How can you modify a boolean setting to include a path

Comment: looks like ChatGPT answer

Comment: I added the following description to settings.json, but it doesn't work well.

"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"files.exclude": { "**/settings.json": true }

If I made some mistakes, could you point out it?